# Bean definition for using a class with static methods in Spring Controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a TestUtil class that I need to use in almost each of my other classes in a Spring MVC web application.

In my application context, I have done the following bean definitions:

```
<bean id="masterbo" class="com.bo.master.MasterBO">
    <property name="masterdao" ref="masterdao"></property>
    <property name="testutil" ref="testutil"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="masterdao" parent="daoSupport" class="com.dao.master.MasterDAO"></bean>
<bean id="testutil" class="com.util.TestUtil"></bean>
```

I have autowired the TestUtil class in MasterBO and simply used the testutil.someMethod() call.

Using this I am able to use the static method from TestUtil in MasterBO. Now, I would like to do the same in the MasterController. Similar bean definition is not working in that case

Can anyone guide me regarding the bean definition that needs to be done?

EDIT: Calling static methods directly is working on Tomcat. Facing this issue on WildFly and JBoss, which supposedly require proper bean definition.

SOLVED: It seems there was an incorrect ParseException being used in the Util which was conflicting with WildFly

Comment: Why do you want to autowire bean to use static methods?

Comment: You don't need to inject a utility class with static methods.

Comment: The problem is that JBoss/WildFly is not allowing the application to start otherwise, directly using it on Tomcat is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate a bean to call a static method, just call the method directly by the class itself: `TestUtil.someMethod()`.

Comment: I have been using it that way on Tomcat, for some reason my application isn't starting on WildFly with the class that contains static methods.